# Avoiding Comments w/ C++ getline()

Tags: c++

I'm using getline() to open a .cpp file.

```
getline(theFile, fileData);
```

I'm wondering if there is any way to have getline() avoid grabbing c++ comments (`/*, */` and `//`)?

So far, trying something like this doesn't quite work.

```
if (fileData[i] == '/*')
```

Comment: I guess `'/*'` is not one character

Comment: Note that '/* */' comments can span on multiple lines, so single line solution won't be enough here.

Comment: Using that string, your program would choke on its own source.

Comment: I would opt for c++11 regexes, you can easily make a naive parser with that in a couple of lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's unavoidable for you to read the comments, but you can dispose of them by reading through the file one character at a time.

To do this, you can load the file into a string and build a state machine with the following states:

1. This is actual code
2. The previous character was `/`
3. The previous character was `*`
4. I am a single-line comment
5. I am a multi-line comment

The state machine starts in **State 1**

If the machine is in **State 1** and hits a `/` character, transition to **State 2**.

If the machine is in **State 2** and hits a `/` character, transition to **State 4**. Otherwise, transition to **State 1**.

If the machine is in **State 2** and hits a `*` character, transition to **State 5**. Otherwise, transition to **State 1**.

If the machine is in **State 4** and hits a *newline* character, transition to **State 1**.

If the machine is in **State 5** and hits a `*` character, transition to **State 3**.

If the machine is in **State 3** and hits a `/` character, transition to **State 1** (the multi-line comment ends). Otherwise, transition to **State 5**.

If you mark the positions of the characters where the machine enters and exits the comment states, you can then strip these characters from the string.

Alternatively, you could explore regular expressions, which provide ways of describing this kind of state machine very succinctly.

Comment: In state 1, you need to at least add a check for strings -- and then handle a possible escaped `\"` inside that string, and *double* escapes. On the plus side, the alternative C++ `//` comments can be added straight away (and then only check end-of-line).

Comment: The state machine would also need to have states for being inside a string (or a multibyte character). One can find a simple filter written in C that converts `//` style comments into `/* */` comments here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12000755/12711  it could be used as a starting point for  filter that strips comments from a stream completely.

Comment: And this is, ladies and gentlemen, underscores that writing even a "simple" lexer to only deal with a subset of C/C++ is not a trivial matter...

Answer (score 3):

So, one problem is that `if(fileData[i] == '/*')` is testing if the `char` `fileData[i]` is equal to `'/*'` which is... Not a `char`.

To find if a line contains a comment, you will probably want to look into one of the following:

- [`<regex>` in C++11](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex) (Boost has a regular expression library as well, if that's more your thing.)
- [`strstr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strstr) in vanilla C/C++.

For multi-line comments, you'll probably want to store something like store a flag indicating whether the state of the previous line was "in comment" or not, and then search for `/*` or `*/` according to that flag, updating it as you go.

Answer (score 0):

Single quotation marks designate a `char`, and the `char` data type represent a SINGLE `char.`'/*' doesn't make sense, because it's two `char` while `fileData[i]` refers to a single `char`.

Your `if` statement needs to be far more robust.