# Change formatting of inline comments from // to /* */

Tags: regex, sed

I have a C file with multiple inline comments that begin with //.
For example,

```
    u32 Status;                                                              

    // Read foo peripherals status                                   
    Status =  foo_periph_status(foo_Instance);

    // Check if foo is ready to turn right                                  
    if ((Status) & (FOO_STATUS_TURN_RIGHT_MASK)) {                          

        // Get FOO current state                                            
        foo_Instance->CurrentState = Foo_GetCurrentState(incoming_data);

        // Get FOO format                                                   
        foo_Instance->CurrentState.metadata.Format = Foo_GetFormat(incoming_data)
```

In above code I'll like to change all the `// inline comments` from their current format to a `/* Inline comments */` format.

I've tried to used,
`s/\([^.*]\)\(\/\/\)\(.*\)\($\)/\1\/\*\3 \*\//`
and this works for me now.

I'm wondering if there is a better way of doing this?

Comment: Your problem is more related to `sed` or other tools than to C language. You might add other tags better suitable.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26344512/replace-single-line-javascript-comments-with-multiline-style-comments-in-notepad (the NPP solution can be used in perl).

Comment: Do you want to take care about comments like this: `// comment */ more comment...`

Comment: @Gerhardh The syntax itself is from C though, so it is fine to use the tag even if the question isn't about C programming.

Comment: There are many code-reformatting tools available if you just search a little.

Comment: @Lundin correct, I didn't suggest to remove C tag. I just suggested adding tags related to the tools to be used.

Comment: Out of interest, why the deuce would you want to do that?

Comment: *"I'm wondering if there is a better way of doing this?"* - Is there any problems with that method?

Comment: You don't need the 1st group for the text before the comment, and you don't need a capture group for the `//`, so you can simplify your `sed` command. If you use a different separator instead of `/`, e.g. `#`, you don't need to escape the `/` that should be part of the pattern or the replacement. `s#//\(.*\)$#/*\1 */#`. As with your original command this will produce a wrong result if you have `*/` in a comment or if you have `//` in a string. This would result in errors from the compiler after the change in most cases.

Comment: what is with multi-line comments that have an `//` on each line?

Comment: what is with // in strings or comments(e.g. from URIs)?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? `//`  is perfectly legal in C99 or C11. The only reason would be to go to C89, and doing that in 2019 is simply not reasonable.

Comment: Another case to consider is if // occurs inside an existing /* comment block - you don't want to convert it at all. But this is all so last-millennium, now that C supports single-line comments, and many compilers supported them long before the standard did.

Comment: To answer your specific question - `s://\(.*\):/*\1*/:` is better than `s/\([^.*]\)\(\/\/\)\(.*\)\($\)/\1\/\*\3 \*\//` in that it's more concise. It's still not robust of course.

Comment: I've voted to reopen because, whatever possible problems the question has, it's certainly about programming.

Comment: I think cleanest would be `sed -E 's#//(.*)#/* \1 */#'`. Also, I very much doubt that the OP needs or cares about robustness, for this scenario.

Comment: This is a duplicate of <https://stackoverflow.com/q/12000001/6872717>.  However, as it is closed I can't flag it as such.  That one has a much better answer than mine.

Answer (score 4):

*EDIT* :

See this old answer that is much better than mine (also written in C): https://stackoverflow.com/a/12000755/6872717.

---

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


#define ARRAY_SIZE(arr) (sizeof(arr) / sizeof((arr)[0]))
#define ARRAY_SSIZE(arr) ((ptrdiff_t)ARRAY_SIZE(arr))


// Read line from file
fgets(buff, BUFSIZ, fp_r);

// Find "//" comment
p = strstr(buff, "//");
if (!p)
        continue;

// If comment is at the very end of the buffer, and wouldn't fit, remove it.
if ((p - &buff[0] + strlen("/**/\n") + 1) > ARRAY_SSIZE(buff)) {
        sprintf(p, "\n");
        continue;
}

// Remove "*/" that would break the new comment format
do {
        q = strstr(p, "*/");
        if (q)
                memmove(q, q + strlen("*/"), strlen(q + strlen("*/")) + 1);
} while (q);

// Write the new comment begining
sprintf(p, "/*");

// Find end of line
p = strrchr(buff, '\n');

// Check that the closing "*/" fits in the buffer
while ((p - &buff[0] + strlen("*/\n") + 1) > ARRAY_SSIZE(buff))
        p--;

// Write closing "*/"
sprintf(p, "*/\n");

// Write line to file
fputs(buff, fp_w);
```

This will fix a line.  You only need to add the code to iterate over the whole file.  You need to have two files open: the one you're reading from (`fp_r`), and a new one (`fp_w`).  You'll have to delete the old file, and after deleting the first one rename the new one with the same name, so that the result is an overwritten file.

This will remove any appearances of `*/` after the `//`.

Problems:

- It will not handle cases where a comment is written in the "`/**/`" format and inside of it contains `//` because it is unlikely, and complicated to solve (see following examples). If this happens, the result may be an invalid comment.
  Examples:

```
a = 7; /* // this will mess everything */
a = /*7*/b; /* // hello, this too */ c=a; // another comment
```

That's in single lines, and it's already complicated. Just imagine to handle it in multiline comments...

- If a `//` is found within a string literal, the same as above happens.  It has a similar difficulty, and it is also unlikely, so I won't bother solving that; it is up to you if you need it :). The result will be invalid code, too
  (Thanks to @EdMorton for spotting this one).
- It will truncate a line if a comment is so long that it ends near the end of the buffer. However, the resulting comment will be valid.

Proposal for these problems:

Prompt the user if a `/*` or `*/` or `"` is detected within a line that will be modified before actually writing it into the file, show him both the original and the modification (you would need to keep a copy of the original one), and let him decide if he prefers the old line or the new one.  And let the user modify manually those lines after this has done most of the job ;-)

The problem with multiline comments (or multiline string literals, bot those are unicorns) would still exist, but maybe you could find another pattern in those, like for example a   `*` at the very beginning of the line.  Anyway, the code wouldn't be invalid; just some unwanted changes inside comments would happen.

Another solution might be to prompt the user at every change.

Comment: Is that literally a solution to this problem in C? :)

Comment: @AlexHarvey Yes. Although I have some knowledge of shell, when things start to complicate such as in this case, for me C is the simplest solution :)

Comment: I guess sometimes the right tool for the job is C, because you just know it really, really well. ;-)

Comment: The other common problem with tasks like this is handling matching strings within strings, for example `printf("hello // world\n");`. I'm assuming that'd be a problem for your code too. I also wonder what your `Remove "*/" ...` code would do with `printf("hello */ world\n");` in various contexts. The OP is asking for trouble anyway though .... :-). I'm actually surprised there isn't an option for some C beautifier to convert `//`-style to `/*..*/`-style comments to output K&R-style code but a quick google didn't produce anything.

Comment: @EdMorton True, I didn't think about string literals I'll add that to the warnings in the answer. The removal of `*/` only starts to the right of "//" so it would only affect comments (or the exceptions).